# Cycling though css values in Firefox's style editor

Tags: firefox, web-development, firefox-developer-tools

In Firebug, when editing some css property, I can press up and down to cycle through all the possible values.

So if I'm editing the "color" property, and I press up/down, it will cycle through "red", "green", "blue", etc. Very convenient.

Is this possible in Firefox's built-in devtools?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i` to open Firefox's devtools. I can scroll through different hex values for a background color property. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MC10 Maybe color was a bad example. If I use "display" or "font-weight" or something else, in Firebug, it'll cycle through all possible values. In the FF devtools it does not. Sometimes it does, but only the "-moz-" values, nothing else.

Comment: I can't either, only colors work for me.

Comment: @MC10 Well then I guess it isn't possible, yet. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version Firefox 49 it is definitive possible:
[image: css value choice in FF49 dev tools]

With the arrow keys you can shuffle through allowed values, but also increase/decrease lengths.